# Move files to root when my NPM package is installed

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

I currently have my repo https://github.com/Aotik/Blossom which I'm working on at the moment. It is a NPM published package named `blossom-ui`

My question is, is there a way to move the files out of `node_modules/blossom-ui` into the root of the folder outside `node_modules` when the package is installed?

So it would look something like

`blossom-ui`

- `css`/
- `styl`/
- `fonts`/
- `js`/

`node_modules`

- `...`

Comment: The whole point of the `node_modules` directory is *that's where the dependencies go*. Why does your package need to be elsewhere?

Comment: I would like to move the compiled files (such as CSS & JS) out of `node_modules` so they can be targeted easily

Comment: I would still like to keep source files in `node_modules` so that I can build a `build` script later on.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done in a `postinstall` script in npm.

`postinstall` is executed automatically by npm each time an `npm install` finishes.

```
    "scripts": {
            "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
            "postinstall": "cp node_modules/blossom-ui ."
    },
```

more info: [npm site scripts page](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `grunt`, a simple [copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) task will make it like this :

```
copy: {
    vendor: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'node_modules/bootstrap/',
            src: ['js/**', 'less/**'],
            dest: 'public/vendor/bootstrap/'
        }]
    }
}
.....
grunt.registerTask('build', ['copy:vendor']);
```

For instance [Drywall project](https://github.com/jedireza/drywall) use it to copy bootstrap & backbone to `/public/vendor` like above. If you check its [gruntfile.js](https://github.com/jedireza/drywall/blob/master/Gruntfile.js).

Keep in mind that your destination folder must be present in your `.gitignore` if you copy from `node_modules`