# node: move files in create-react-app template to root post-install

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544993/move-files-to-root-when-my-npm-package-is-installed) with a twist:

I'm building out a `create-react-app` [template](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/custom-templates/) that uses both electron and redux.

I want to move config files for webpack and babel from a `/src/config` directory to root on post install. However, adding `"postinstall": "cp /src/config ."` to my `package.json` file isn't working. Looks like that file and not `template.json` is the right place to add the postinstall script, but for some reason, possibly due to how the templating system manages internal file structures (?) this script is running after install but failing. I have the config files at `/template/src/config` in my published package.

EDIT: Looks like it runs if I change the postinstall script to `"cp template/src/config/* ."` but it doesn't copy any files over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution to this was easy: if you want files in template root, put them in the /template directory.

Comment: Thank you. I am happy to know that the solution had worked.

Answer (score 5):

File copying after build can be achieved reliably on all operating systems by using the ***ncp*** package and an associated script.

**How to copy the files after react build?**

**1. Add ncp as a dependency in 'package.json'**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ncp": "2.0.0",
    ....
  }
```

**2. Create a file-copy script that will recursively copy files from source to destination**

```
// File name: file-copy.js

var path = require('path');
var ncp = require('ncp').ncp;

ncp.limit = 16;

var srcPath = 'src/config'
var destPath = 'dst/config'

console.log('Copying files...');
ncp(srcPath, destPath, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log('Copying files complete.');
});
```

**3. Add 'node file-copy.js' as an additional step to the build process in package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    ...  

    "build": "react-scripts build && node file-copy.js"

    ...
  },
```

**Note:** After updating the package.json, run the `npm install` once to install / enable ncp package.

**Alternative:**
`npm add ncp` on latest version of nodejs will update package.json and also enable ncp in single step.

**4. Test the build process by running 'npm run build'**

```
$ npm run build

> ui@0.1.0 build /Users/macuser1/stack-overflow/ui
> react-scripts build && node file-copy.js

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  40.32 KB         build/static/js/2.db436670.chunk.js
  1.24 KB (-20 B)  build/static/js/main.02386c69.chunk.js
  767 B            build/static/js/runtime-main.873e104b.js

...

Copying files...
Copying files complete.
Copying files complete.
$
```

Comment: Looks like this is not working if I'm using the "build" entry in the root package.json for the template. The install script doesn't look like it's invoking the copy script.

Comment: ncp package must be enabled by running 'npm install' or 'npm add' command once. After this, the copying will work. Also, the file copying functionality can be tested directly by running 'node file-copy.js'